# Persist using stored procedure with return id

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

PostgreSQL 9.1, Hibernate 4.1.

How can I persist PropertyTypeEntity using stored procedure (problem in return id. GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
It impossible?

```
@Table(name = "property_types", schema = "public", catalog = "")
@Entity
public class PropertyTypeEntity implements IEntity<Long> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Does the stored procedure only generate the ID, or it does the whole insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least following two ways:

1. Use [SQLInsert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert.html), though I have no idea is there interoperability issues with JPA annotations
2. Create custom generator, some example can be found from [this](http://danu-javastuff.blogspot.de/2009/01/custom-id-generator-class-for-hibernate.html) blog post.